# Insert unicode character in auctex math mode

Tags: math-mode, unicode, emacs, auctex

I use emacs with auctex to run lualatex. Is there a way to modify the math input of auctex, e.g. modify LaTeX-math-zeta, bound to the keystroke <`z>, so the unicode character ζ instead of `\zeta` is written?

I thought of redefining the function LaTeX-math-insert, but could not figure out how this could be done.

Comment: mistake, my error...

Comment: one dumb way to do it, is to redefine the LaTeX-math-... commands in .emacs:                    
 `(defun LaTeX-math-zeta ()
  "Insert ζ"
  (interactive)
  (insert "ζ" ))
`'

Comment: How do you plan to insert the `ζ` character?  Depending on that, it may or may not be possible to do what you ask.

Answer (score 2):

This is the purpose of preview-latex. Here, with auctex 11.89, with the cursor on the math item, just type `C-c C-p C-p` and the editor displays the ζ .

Comment: thank you for your answer. I know and use preview-latex. What I want to do is to insert unicode characters directly.

Answer (score 2):

Not elegant, but it works for me: I just use my dumb solution and define a function for each character I need. What I have so far is

```lisp
(defun LaTeX-math-alpha  () "Insert α" (interactive) (insert "α" ))
(defun LaTeX-math-approx () "Insert ≈" (interactive) (insert "≈" ))
(defun LaTeX-math-beta   () "Insert β" (interactive) (insert "β" ))
(defun LaTeX-math-delta  () "Insert δ" (interactive) (insert "δ" ))
(defun LaTeX-math-epsilon() "Insert ϵ" (interactive) (insert "ϵ" ))
(defun LaTeX-math-zeta   () "Insert ζ" (interactive) (insert "ζ" ))
(defun LaTeX-math-eta    () "Insert η" (interactive) (insert "η" ))
(defun LaTeX-math-theta  () "Insert θ" (interactive) (insert "θ" ))
(defun LaTeX-math-iota   () "Insert ι" (interactive) (insert "ι" ))
(defun LaTeX-math-kappa  () "Insert κ" (interactive) (insert "κ" ))
(defun LaTeX-math-lambda () "Insert λ" (interactive) (insert "λ" ))
(defun LaTeX-math-mu     () "Insert μ" (interactive) (insert "μ" ))
(defun LaTeX-math-nu     () "Insert ν" (interactive) (insert "ν" ))
(defun LaTeX-math-xi     () "Insert ξ" (interactive) (insert "ξ" ))
(defun LaTeX-math-pi     () "Insert π" (interactive) (insert "π" ))
(defun LaTeX-math-rho    () "Insert ρ" (interactive) (insert "ρ" ))
(defun LaTeX-math-sigma  () "Insert σ" (interactive) (insert "σ" ))
(defun LaTeX-math-tau    () "Insert τ" (interactive) (insert "τ" ))
(defun LaTeX-math-upsilon() "Insert υ" (interactive) (insert "υ" ))
(defun LaTeX-math-phi    () "Insert ϕ" (interactive) (insert "ϕ" ))
(defun LaTeX-math-chi    () "Insert χ" (interactive) (insert "χ" ))
(defun LaTeX-math-psi    () "Insert ψ" (interactive) (insert "ψ" ))
(defun LaTeX-math-omega  () "Insert ω" (interactive) (insert "ω" ))
(defun LaTeX-math-varepsilon()"Insert ε" (interactive) (insert "ε" ))
(defun LaTeX-math-vartheta   () "Insert ϑ" (interactive) (insert "ϑ" ))
(defun LaTeX-math-varpi      () "Insert ϖ" (interactive) (insert "ϖ" ))
(defun LaTeX-math-varrho     () "Insert ϱ" (interactive) (insert "ϱ" ))
(defun LaTeX-math-varsigma   () "Insert ς" (interactive) (insert "ς" ))
(defun LaTeX-math-varphi () "Insert φ" (interactive) (insert "φ" ))

(defun LaTeX-math-cdot   () "Insert ⋅" (interactive) (insert "⋅" ))
(defun LaTeX-math-dif    () "Insert " (interactive) (insert "" ))
(defun LaTeX-math-ell    () "Insert ℓ" (interactive) (insert "ℓ" ))
(defun LaTeX-math-iiint  () "Insert ∭" (interactive) (insert "∭" ))
(defun LaTeX-math-iint   () "Insert ∬" (interactive) (insert "∬" ))
(defun LaTeX-math-in     () "Insert ∈" (interactive) (insert "∈" ))
(defun LaTeX-math-int    () "Insert ∫" (interactive) (insert "∫" ))
(defun LaTeX-math-itrans () "Insert ⊷" (interactive) (insert "⊷" ))
(defun LaTeX-math-partial() "Insert ∂" (interactive) (insert "∂" ))
(defun LaTeX-math-sum    () "Insert ∑" (interactive) (insert "∑" ))
(defun LaTeX-math-transf ()"Insert ⊶" (interactive) (insert "⊶" ))

(defun LaTeX-math-Rarrow () "Insert ⇒" (interactive) (insert "⇒" ))
(defun LaTeX-math-rarrow () "Insert →" (interactive) (insert "→" ))
```

With my LaTeX-math-list:

```lisp
(setq LaTeX-math-list '(
         ("ä (" "left" nil nil)
         ("ä )" "right" nil nil)
         ("ä =" "approx" "personal" 8776)
         ("ä F" "dfrac" nil nil)
         ("ä I" "iint" "personal" 8748)
         ("ä R" "Rarrow" "personal" 8658)
         ("ä T" "itrans" "personal" 8887 )
         ("ä d"  "dif" "personal" 100)
         ("ä f" "frac"  nil nil)
         ("ä i" "int" "personal" 8747)
         ("ä j" "iiint" "personal" 8749)
         ("ä l" "ell"     "personal" 8467 )
         ("ä p" "partial" "personal" 8706)
         ("ä r" "rarrow" "personal" 8594)
         ("ä s" "sum"    "personal" 8721)
         ("ä t" "transf" "personal" 8886 )
        ))
```